# Why don't all methods inherit from the class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

Just for example:

```py
class Foo:
    def wrapper(func):
        def wrapped(self):
            try:
                return func(self)
            except Exception:
                raise
            finally:
                print('Some error in wrapped function')
        return wrapped

    @wrapper
    def division(self, x, y):
        return x / y


class Bar(Foo):
    @wrapper
    def multiplication(self, x, y):
        return x * y


f = Foo()
print(f.division(5, 2))

b = Bar()
print(b.multiplication(3, 3))
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Dev\abc-python\count.py", line 18, in <module>
    class Bar(Foo):
  File "d:\Dev\abc-python\count.py", line 20, in Bar     
    @wrapper
NameError: name 'wrapper' is not defined
```

When inheriting, I expect that the child class will have all the methods of the parent, I did not find the reverse information, at least I see no reason why the `wrapper` is not inherited by the child class.

Yes, I can move the decorators into a separate file and import them, maybe it will be "more correct", but I want to understand why they are not inherited.

Comment: None of those names are in scope in the class block. They are members of the parent class namespace, so it is available at `Foo.wrapper`. This has nothing really to do with inheritance. *It is inherited*, but `Bar` doesn't exist yet when the class definition is being executed.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga wait, why can I call the ```division``` method in the ```Bar``` class, but can't do it with a ```wrapper```? some thoughts began to arise in my head, but I still do not quite understand the logic of this.

Comment: The other option is to do the decoration after the class definition, `Foo.multiplication = Foo.wrapper(Foo.multiplication)`

Comment: You *cannot* call the `division` method *from the `Bar` class definition statement.* Both `wrapper` and `division` would not be in that scope (which is the fundamental issue here). Go ahead, try it. In the class defnition of `Bar` write `division(1,1)` and you will get a `NameError`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga how I was so stupid. These methods are available on an instance of the class, but they are not in the spoce of the child class. Where is my coffee =) Thank you, I think you should write an answer.

Comment: well, they are available either through the instance as a bound method, `instance.division` or directly on the class, `Bar.division` (after the class definition statement). I think what you are expecting is Python scope to work like Java/ C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of those names are in scope in the class block. They are members of the parent class namespace, so it is available at `Foo.wrapper`. This has nothing really to do with inheritance. *It is inherited*, **but `Bar` doesn't exist yet when the class definition is being executed.**

This works the same with any attribute that belongs to the parent namespace, when you are trying to use it in the class scope of the child class definition statement.

```
 In [1]: class Foo:
   ...:     def division(self, x, y): return x/y
   ...:

In [2]: class Bar(Foo):
   ...:     division(1,1)
   ...:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-03e47cf52ab3> in <module>
----> 1 class Bar(Foo):
      2     division(1,1)
      3

<ipython-input-8-03e47cf52ab3> in Bar()
      1 class Bar(Foo):
----> 2     division(1,1)
      3

NameError: name 'division' is not defined
```

To get around this, you can do:

```
class Bar(Foo):

    @Foo.wrapper
    def multiplication(self, x, y):
        return x * y
```

Or:

```
class Bar(Foo):
    
    def multiplication(self, x, y):
        return x * y

Bar.multiplication = Bar.wrapper(Bar.multiplication)
```